# Unable To Parse A Response Object Array In PHP

Tags: php, oop, soap, response

I am trying to integrate a shipping API with my app. I send my details to a SOAP client and I'm recieiving an object array in return which I am unable to parse. Following is the array. Please help me parse this:

```
object(stdClass)#29 (4) {
    ["Transaction"]=>
    object(stdClass)#30 (5) {
        ["Reference1"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Reference2"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Reference3"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Reference4"]=>
        string(0) ""
        ["Reference5"]=>
        string(0) ""
    }
    ["Notifications"]=>
    object(stdClass)#31 (0) {
    }
    ["HasErrors"]=>
    bool(false)
    ["Shipments"]=>
    object(stdClass)#32 (1) {
        ["ProcessedShipment"]=>
        object(stdClass)#33 (8) {
            ["ID"]=>
            string(10) "42939401"
            ["Reference1"]=>
            string(9) "100000002"
            ["Reference2"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["Reference3"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["ForeignHAWB"]=>
            string(0) ""
            ["HasErrors"]=>
            bool(false)
            ["Notifications"]=>
            object(stdClass)#34 (0) {
            }
            ["ShipmentLabel"]=>
                object(stdClass)#35 (2) {
                ["LabelURL"]=>
                string(76) "http://content/rpt_cache/9c0d152bbcdc4e739132d2dsda5506.pdf"
                ["LabelFileContents"]=>
                NULL
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I took this response in `$response` variable and tried the following but none of these work:

```
echo $order    = $response["Shipments"]["ProcessedShipment"]["Reference1"];
echo $hawb     = $response["Shipments"]["ProcessedShipment"]["ID"];
echo $barcode  = $response["Shipments"]["ProcessedShipment"]["ShipmentLabel"]["LabelURL"];
```

I can't try too much because there is no testing framework with the service I have to manually cancel all the shipments I create. Please tell me what to do.

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Comment: It's an object, not an array, that's why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an array, it's an `stdClass` object (a general Object).

You should be using `$response->Shipments->ProcessedShipment->Reference1`

Answer (score 3):

It' object, not an array. You should use `->` to access the property.

```
$order    = $response->Shipments->ProcessedShipment->Reference1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You use `->` operator to access object's property

```
$response->Shipments->ProcessedShipment->Reference1;
$response->Shipments->ProcessedShipment->ID;
$response->Shipments->ProcessedShipment->ShipmentLabel->LabelURL;
```